# how to access text of a dropdownlist not it's value when submiting the form to controller in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to access text and value both of them from dropdownlist in in controller!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFKVy.png)
in this pic which you can see I need to access Import Duty text in controller when I submit the form!!!

```
public ActionResult Index(){ string taxtype=Request["TaxType"];//this shows the value I need this to access it's text like
string txt=Request["TaxType"].Text; }
```

Comment: You can use hidden field to hold text value of DDL before submit the form (use `onchange` event) & submit them together. Any code sample/solution you've tried then?

Comment: you can use Viewdata,viewbag,hiddenfield to hold your value and pass them to controller.

Comment: If the page is designed properly, your application should be able to infer the text from the value.

Comment: in the value I store the codes but in text I store names and I access both of them when I submit the form!
@TetsuyaYamamoto and Dear Deepak I Know using HiddenField but I am searching for a direct way!!!

Comment: Can you the code used to populate the dropdown

Comment: @EngMohammadJalalAhmadzai What's "direct way" you mean - by submitting the form then it automatically search DDL text based from corresponding submitted value? If you have `List<SelectListItem>` property in viewmodel to pass into DDL, use `Where` on that list.

Comment: Alternatively you can populate a `Dictionary` object with dropdownlist values set as its key - and dropdownlist texts as its value. Submit the form and use `Key` property to reveal corresponding dropdown text from controller action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do like, you need to fire javascript function on your drop down selection change and set that text to hidden text box and pass that value to your action method like below

This will be your html code.

```
 <select id="TaxType" name="TaxType" onchange="SetTaxTextValue();">
                <option value="op1">Option1</option>
                <option value="op2">Option2</option>
                <option value="op3">Option3</option>
                <option value="op4">Option4</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" style="visibility:hidden" id="txtTax" name="txtTax" />
```

Below is javascript function

```
function SetTaxTextValue() {
        var taxText = $("#TaxType option:selected").text();;
        $("#txtTax").val(taxText);
    }
```

and your controller action will be below

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string TaxType, string txtTax)
        {
            string finalVal = TaxType + txtTax;
            return View();
        }
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to access text and value both of them from dropdownlist in in controller! enter image description here in this pic which you can see I need to access Import Duty text in controller when I submit the form!!!
>
> in the value I store the codes but in text I store names and I access both of them when I submit the form! @TetsuyaYamamoto and Dear Deepak I Know using HiddenField but I am searching for a direct way!!! –

Here are two very common ways to handle this.

(1) Store both the code *and the text* in the `value` attribute. The web application can parse the submitted value and thereby obtain both the code and the text. For example,

```
    <SELECT>
        <OPTION Value="1|One">One</OPTION>
        <OPTION Value="2|Two">Two</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
```

(2) Store a lookup table that maps value to text. The form only submits the value and the web application uses that value to obtain the text. It's often the case that you would use the exact same table to render the page to begin with.